# addChildViewController and autolayout of the subviews

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am having trouble using the addChildViewController to implement a top bar (like the navigation controller bar but custom).
I created this bar in a .xib file and added the buttons and images with the proper autolayout constraint.

I don't know in which method of my controller to add this bar. My controller has an empty view in the space where I want the header to go.

```
    let customHeader = HeaderViewController(nibName: "HeaderViewController",bundle: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(customHeader)
    customHeader.view.frame = self.headerView.frame
    self.view.addSubview(customHeader.view)
    customHeader.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

If I put this lines of code in viewWillApear or viewDidLoad frame of the headeView (the empty view where I want to add the subview) is not the right one yet.
If I do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews it get called many times.

Where should I put it? Or I can I fixed the layout problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to add layout constraints to the constrain the `customHeader.view` in `self.headerView`?

Comment: self.headerView is just a white view with constraints to the rest of the element in the mainViewController. Like 0 space to top layout, leading, trailling and bottom space. And the customHeader view already has layout for the elements that he has, like an image an a couple of buttons

Comment: It would still probably be wise to constraint `customHeader.view` at least to the leading/trialing/top/bottom of `self.headerView`, if that's really the size/place you want it to have.

Comment: even if customHeader.view is not a subview of self.headerView? It's suppose to take his place, but it's not a subview.

Comment: Well, it isn't taking it's place in your code, it's just potentially covering it up.  You don't have to constraint `customHeader.view` to `self.headerView`, you can constraint it in another way, you should probably constraint it somehow, though.

Comment: I was able to fixit adding the constraints to the main view with VFL in ViewDidLoad. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints to `customHeader.view` after you add it to `self.view` so that your layout is fully specified (what you're doing now might work, but it depends on if `self.headerView` is already what you want it to be).  You could do something like the following:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customHeader.view, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customHeader.view, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customHeader.view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customHeader.view, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```